What is the compatible version of jBPM for Java 17, SpringBoot 2.7.0, Hibernate 5.6.9.Final?
What is the compatible version of jBPM for Java 17, SpringBoot 2.7.0, Hibernate 5.6.9.Final?
We have below configuration in our project and we need to add compatible version of jBPM -
Java : 17
SpringBoot : 2.7.0
SpringFramework : 5.3.20
Maven : 3.9.5
h2 : 1.4.199
Hibernate : 5.6.9.Final
hibernate-jpamodelgen : 5.6.9.FInal
JBPM : Currently using 7.57.0.Final (Tried with 7.57.0.Final & 7.70.0.Final)
GWT : 2.10.0
smartGWT : 13.0p
jaxb-api : 2.3.3
jaxb-impl : 2.3.3
jaxb-runtime : 2.3.3
jtython : 2.7.2
JBPM : Currently using 7.57.0.Final (Tried with 7.57.0.Final & 7.70.0.Final)

the upcoming Apache KIE version 10 will support JDK 17 and SpringBoot 3.2.4. Apache KIE is the project that currently maintains and innovates jBPMN and other Business Automation tools like drools.
jBPMN 7.x is no longer maintained, so I strongly suggest considering a migration to Apache KIE 10.0.0.
